# Is there any harm in creating a index that is a subset of unique clustered index?

Tags: indexing, sap-ase

I have a table `ABC` and a unique clustered index on below columns

```
col1, col2, col4, col5, col6
```

It's a vast table and analyzing most of the queries on this table I feel that a new index of below columns would help.

```
col1, col5, col2
```

But, I am not sure of the performance impact and need to know whether it;s a good idea to create this additional index. So, basically can we have a index that has columns that are subset of a unique clustered index (also with order changed)?

Haven't found anything related while searching internet. Any hint's/thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As indexes are computational used to rapidly access data, you can have several indexes which overlaps without problems for **reading** data. So your solution of index with (col1, col5, col2) as one index and (col1, col2, col4, col5, col6) as another is usable and also does not deal with performance issue for **reading** data.

Of course, as any index comes with a cost when adding data (must write also the index), if your table also have a big amount of **write**, you will have loss of time when writing data.